I am trying to return data from current tear and previous year. I keep getting a divide by 0 Error
If I go for data from just current year it works, if I go for data from just previous year it works, when I go with both current and previous I get the divide by 0 error?
Select FISCYR,
  LTrim(RTrim(FISCPER)) as 'Period',
  Customer,
  ORDNUMBER,
  LTrim(RTrim(PONUMBER)) as 'PO Number',
  Item,
  LTrim(RTrim([DESC])) as 'Product',
  Cast(QTY as Decimal(18,2)) As 'QTY',
  CAST(EXTINVMISC/EXTWEIGHT as Decimal(18,2)) as 'Price (Lb)',
  LTrim(RTrim(LOTNUMF)) as 'Lot Num',
  LTrim(RTrim(Location)) as 'Location',
  LTrim(RTrim(VIADESC)) as 'Ship Via'  
From DBO.viewinvoicehistory
Where TRANSTYPE=1
  and fiscyr = Year(GETDATE()) 
   or fiscyr = year(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
  and CUSTNAME='LOBLAW COMPANIES LIMITED.'
Order By FiscYr DESC,LTrim(RTrim(FISCPER)) DESC


first things first, surround your OR condition with parenthesis from fiscyr = Year(GETDATE()) or fiscyr = year(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) to (fiscyr = Year(GETDATE()) or fiscyr = year(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())))

You obviously have records in the previous year where EXTWEIGHT is zero/null

Which dbms are you using? The above SQL is product specific in many ways.

Provide a complete reproducer. E.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/ can be used. Make it easy to assist you!

wow.....that was easy ...Thank you! Jorge

Because I think it is Microsoft SQL Server, rewrite your query as :
SELECT FISCYR,
       TRIM(FISCPER)) as 'Period', --> replace LTrim(RTrim by TRIM
       Customer,
       ORDNUMBER,
       TRIM(PONUMBER)) as 'PO Number',
       Item,
       TRIM([DESC])) as 'Product',
       Cast(QTY as Decimal(18,2)) As 'QTY',
       CAST(EXTINVMISC/NULLIF(EXTWEIGHT, 0) --> use NULIIF function to avoid divide by zero
           as Decimal(18,2)) as 'Price (Lb)',
       TRIM(LOTNUMF)) as 'Lot Num',
       TRIM(Location)) as 'Location',
       TRIM(VIADESC)) as 'Ship Via'  
FROM   dbo.viewinvoicehistory --> dbo not DBO
WHERE  TRANSTYPE = 1
       and (fiscyr = Year(GETDATE()) --> probable logical mistake
            or fiscyr = year(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())))
       and CUSTNAME = 'LOBLAW COMPANIES LIMITED.'
ORDER  BY FiscYr DESC, TRIM(FISCPER)) DESC;

TRIM instaed of RTRIM(LTRIM(... was firts introduce with the 2017 version of SQL Server
